do-release-upgrade fails due to usrmerge and Smartmatch
I cannot upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04.1 because do-release-upgrade stops and claiming usr isn't merged.
But if I run usrmerge as root, it comes up with a message, that it successfully merged usr.
But there is an error nevertheless. Maybe it quits with exit 1 I thought, but that seems not to be the case. echo $? returns 0.
I created a wrapper script that calls usrmerge and exits with 0. But do-release-upgrade still fails, claiming usr isn't merged and I should install the package usrmerge to solve the issue.
$ sudo LANG=C do-release-upgrade
  Checking for a new Ubuntu release

  = Welcome to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS 'Noble Numbat' =
   
  [...]
  
  Reading state information... Done

  Cannot upgrade system with unmerged /usr 

  Please install the usrmerge package to fix this, and then try the 
  upgrade again. 


  Restoring original system state

  Aborting
  Reading package lists... Done    
  Building dependency tree... Done 
  Reading state information... Done
  === Command detached from window (Thu Oct 17 23:28:58 2024) ===
  === Command terminated with exit status 1 (Thu Oct 17 23:29:08      2024) ===

I wrote a wrapper script but it return 0, like the original script, despite the original throws out that warning on Smartmatch at line 172.
$ sudo cat /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge
#!/bin/bash
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge_bin 2> /dev/null
exit 0

Running the wrapper
$ sudo LANG=C /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge
The system has been successfully converted.

Running the usrmerge script directly
$ sudo LANG=C /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge_bin
  Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge_bin line 172.
  The system has been successfully converted.
$ echo $?
  0

$ LANG=C apt policy usrmerge
usrmerge:
  Installed: 25ubuntu2
  Candidate: 25ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 25ubuntu2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64  Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ sudo LANG=C sha1sum /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge_bin
ddc18b09fdc448c2d8aa2c94669501500482388e  /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge_bin
$ sudo LANG=C cat -n /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge_bin | egrep '^[[:space:]]*172'
   172      if (-e "/usr$n" && $n ~~ @generated_files) {
$ sudo LANG=C cat -n /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge_bin | egrep -C10 '^[[:space:]]*172'
   162          fatal("Both $n and /usr$n exist");
   163      }
   164  
   165      # generated files
   166      # if it was already re-generated in the new place, clear the legacy location
   167      # Origin of generated files:
   168      # /lib/udev/hwdb.bin -> 'systemd-hwdb --usr update'
   169      my @generated_files = qw(
   170          /lib/udev/hwdb.bin
   171      );
   172      if (-e "/usr$n" && $n ~~ @generated_files) {
   173          rm('-f', "$n");
   174          return;
   175      }
   176  
   177      fatal("$n is a directory and /usr$n is not")
   178          if -d $n and -e "/usr$n";
   179      fatal("/usr$n is a directory and $n is not")
   180          if -d "/usr$n";
   181      fatal("Both $n and /usr$n exist")
   182          if -e "/usr$n";

Here is a strace output
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/c3wghnxPJ7/
I edited convert-usrmerge to avoid the warning, which works
use lib "/usr/lib/usrmerge/lib";
use warnings;

# https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/60b3tr/ how_to_suppress_experimental_warning_for/
# to solve https://askubuntu.com/questions/1530232/do-release-upgrade-fails-due-to-usrmerge-and-smartmatch
no if $] >= 5.018, warnings =>  "experimental::smartmatch";
use feature "switch";

use strict;
use autodie;

But unfortunately it didn't solve that do-release-upgrade claims usr isn't merged and complain about it and doesn't start the upgrade process.
So Smartmatch doesn't seem to be the culprit.
I don't know how to debug a perlscript, but I post my attempt anyway:
$ sudo LANG=C perl -d /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.60
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:27):
27: my $Debug = 1;
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:28):
28: my $Program_RC = 0;
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:30):
30: check_free_space();
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:32):
32: go_faster();
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:35):
35: $SIG{__DIE__} = sub { fatal($_[0]); };
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:38):
38:     foreach my $name (early_conversion_files()) {
  DB<1> n
    main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:38):
38:     foreach my $name (early_conversion_files()) {
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:43):
43:     my @dirs = directories_to_merge();
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:46):
46:     foreach my $dir (@dirs) {
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:47):
47:         mkdir("/usr$dir") if not -e "/usr$dir";
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:47):
47:         mkdir("/usr$dir") if not -e "/usr$dir";
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:47):
47:         mkdir("/usr$dir") if not -e "/usr$dir";
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:47):
47:         mkdir("/usr$dir") if not -e "/usr$dir";
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:47):
47:         mkdir("/usr$dir") if not -e "/usr$dir";
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:47):
47:         mkdir("/usr$dir") if not -e "/usr$dir";
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:50):
50:     my @later;
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:51):
51:     my $rule = File::Find::Rule->mindepth(1)->maxdepth(1)->start(@dirs);
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:52):
52:     while (defined (my $name = $rule->match)) {
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:58):
58:     convert_file($_) foreach @later;
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:60):
60:     verify_links_only($_) foreach @dirs;
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:62):
62:     convert_directory($_) foreach @dirs;
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:64):
64:     exit($Program_RC) if $Program_RC;
  DB<1> n
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:65):
65:     print "The system has been successfully converted.\n";
  DB<1> n
The system has been successfully converted.
main::(/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge:66):
66:     exit;
  DB<1> n
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
h q, h R or h o to get additional info.
  DB<1> q

As far as i can see usr is already merged
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root           7 Jun 24  2022  bin -> usr/bin
    drwxr-xr-x  44 root    root        4096 Okt 16 11:59  boot
    drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root        4096 Okt  2  2012  cdrom
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root    root        4096 Okt 31  2019  custom
    drwxr-xr-x  22 root    root        5720 Okt 17 23:14  dev
    drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root        4096 Aug 29  2021  dracut
    drwxr-xr-x 244 root    root       20480 Okt 17 23:13  etc
    drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root        4096 Dez 19  2019  export
    drwxr-xr-x   6 root    root        4096 Okt 30  2012  export_ofs
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root    root        4096 Okt  2  2012  home
    drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root        4096 Jan 19  2020  images
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root           8 Mai  6 15:35  lib -> /usr/lib
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root           9 Jun 24  2022  lib32 -> usr/lib32
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root           9 Jun 24  2022  lib64 -> usr/lib64
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root          36 Mär 30  2014  libnss3.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root    root        4096 Mai  5 01:02  lib-rootfolder
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root          10 Jun 24  2022  libx32 -> usr/libx32
    drwx------   2 root    root       16384 Sep 30  2012  lost+found
    drwxr-xr-x   4 root    root        4096 Jul  2  2022  media
    drwxr-xr-x   8 root    root        4096 Feb 22  2022  mnt
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root    root        4096 Okt 31  2012  net
    drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root        4096 Jan 19  2020  NST
    drwxr-xr-x   5 root    root        4096 Jun 24  2022  opt
    dr-xr-xr-x 413 root    root           0 Okt 17 23:14  proc
    drwx------  17 root    root        4096 Okt 18 14:34  root
    drwxr-xr-x  51 root    root        1560 Okt 18 00:00  run
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root           8 Jun 24  2022  sbin -> usr/sbin
    drwxr-xr-x  38 root    root        4096 Aug 10 17:54  snap
    drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root        4096 Apr 25  2012  srv
    dr-xr-xr-x  13 root    root           0 Okt 17 23:14  sys
    drwxrwxrwt  26 root    root       12288 Okt 18 14:45  tmp
    drwxr-xr-x  17 root    root        4096 Jun 24  2022  usr
    drwxr-xr-x  15 root    root        4096 Jun  3  2018  var
    drwxr-xr-x   2 root    root        4096 Sep  2  2020  zfspool
    $ ls -l /usr
    insgesamt 324
    drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 135168 Okt 17 23:13 bin
    drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Okt 17 23:09 games
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 Jun 24  2022 i686-w64-mingw32
    drwxr-xr-x 105 root root  20480 Okt 14 14:33 include
    drwxr-xr-x 203 root root  57344 Okt 16 12:33 lib
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 Jun 26 15:18 lib32
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 Jun 26 15:18 lib64
    drwxr-xr-x  32 root root  12288 Okt 14 14:34 libexec
    drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   4096 Jun 24  2022 libx32
    drwxr-xr-x  12 root root   4096 Mai 21  2022 local
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 Jul 31  2016 locale
    drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  32768 Okt 16 11:59 sbin
    drwxr-xr-x 555 root root  20480 Okt 17 23:09 share
    drwxr-xr-x  19 root root   4096 Okt 16 11:50 src
    drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 Jun 24  2022 x86_64-w64-mingw32

I hope someone knows a workaround.
I only see to manually update my sources.list and do the upgrade without do-release-upgrade, because usrmerge says usr is successfully converted and do-release-upgrade says the opposite, and I can't figure out why.
TIA
floogy

The absolute path in the lib symlink was the culprit
     lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root           8 Mai  6 15:35  lib -> /usr/lib

     cd /
     sudo ln -snf usr/lib lib

     $ ls -l /lib
     lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Okt 18 16:35 /lib -> usr/lib

This solved my issue with usrmerge and do-release-upgrade

Your ls -la / shows that /lib is an absolute symlink:
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root    root           8 Mai  6 15:35  lib -> /usr/lib

I have looked at the code in the 24.04-specific upgrade tool (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/noble.tar.gz, which URL you can find at https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts), and it expects a merged /usr system to have /lib as a relative symlink to usr/lib:
    def _test_and_fail_on_unmerged_usr(self):
        """
        LP: #2058648
        """
        fail = False

        logging.debug('Checking that system is /usr-merged')

        for d in ('/bin', '/sbin', '/lib'):
            try:
                if os.readlink(d) != f'usr{d}':
                    # The file is a symlink, but it's pointing to the wrong
                    # place?
                    fail = True
                    break

You should be able do perform the upgrade if you replace the /lib symlink with a relative one:
sudo ln -sfn usr/lib /lib

Also, I'd report a bug because I think the upgrade tool ought to accept absolute symlinks here.

Thank you, for pointing this out. That solved the issue.

Note that you need to create the links relatively. I had link to /usr/lib and it didn't work. However usr/lib works.
